# Content Security Policy has been added phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-desktop-app

My PhoneGap app is not automatically refreshed when there is a change in any of the file. On desktop's PhoneGap client I can see on the console that it is detecting the change but doesn't refresh the app. I also get this message below:

> Content Security Policy has been added: https://ssl.gstatic.com;img-src 'self' data: content:;style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data: blob:;script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: blob:;">

Does anyone else is also getting this error? If yes, then how to solve it?

Comment: What makes you think that was an _error_ message?

Comment: Nothing, and I said I get this message not an error message. The only reason to point it here is that it wasn't showing before.

Comment: _“ and I said I get this message not an error message”_ – and then you immediately followed the message quote with _“Does anyone else is also getting this error?”_ …